# Set timer for a Django view execution

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling trying to prevent a Django view from being executed more than once within an hour period. In other words, if the function runs at 15:00, all future requests for all users should be ignored until 17:00 when it's allowed to run once more again.

Tried with a timer, but it does get reset every time the view is called. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? Thanks!!!

```
import threading as th

def hello():
    print("hello, world")


def webhook(request):
   
   tm = th.Timer(3600, hello)
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and not tm.is_alive():
        
        tm.start()
        
        code_to.ecexute()

        return HttpResponse("Webhook received!")
```

Comment: That code has an `IndentationError`. Please make sure code examples reflect your real code as closely as possible. We can't be expected to guess which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Comment: In any case, the solution will involve storing the time the function runs somewhere (in your database? In Redis?) and checking against that timestamp whenever somebody tries to run the function. E.g., in pseudocode `webhook() { if ( current_time - threshold < last_run_time ) { return HTTP_400; } else { run_function_logic() } }`.

Comment: @Chris, I really don't need a database. Just a runtime check - do not return anything for an hour once the function has been executed.

Comment: You're going to need to store your state somewhere. That's what data stores are for. If this is a small, one-server machine you could even use a text file (though that won't scale well). Storing a timestamp every time your function runs and checking against the last timestamp when it tries to run again is a much better solution than trying to keep a timer running somewhere.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your help - I ended up using a simple text file for storing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this is what I did and it seems to work fine. I actually need it to run no more than once a day, hence the conditional below.

Thanks for all the suggestions!!!

```
def webhook2 (request):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    with open('timestamp.txt') as f:
        tstamp = f.read()
        last_run = datetime.strptime(tstamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
        last_run_date = datetime.date(last_run)
        print ("last run: " + str(last_run_date))
        

    if last_run_date < today:

        
        file = open("timestamp.txt" ,"w")
        file.write(str(today))
        file.close()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            msg = str(request.body)
            final_msg=msg[2:-1]
            print("Data received from Webhook is: ", request.body)

            # creates a google calendar event
            function_logic()

            return HttpResponse("Webhook received! Event added to calendar")
    
    
    else:
        print ("we already have a record for today")

        return HttpResponse("Not adding a record. We already have one for today.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is being reset everytime because it is inside a function that is execute everytime when request is being made.
You should try to set the timer globally, such as outside your function. ( be aware when your script will re-run, timer will be reset again ).

```
import threading as th

def hello():
    print("hello, world")

tm = None

def webhook(request):
   
    # check here if timer is dead then process the request.
    if timer_is_dead || tm is None:
        
        # accessing global value and setting it for first time
        if tm is None:
            global tm
            tm =  th.Timer(3600, hello)
            tm.start()
        
        if request.method == 'POST' and not tm.is_alive():
     
            code_to.ecexute()

            # start timer again for next hour
            
            return HttpResponse("Webhook received!")
    else:
        return HttResponse("Not Allowed")
```

Edit: Handling first request and then starting timer

Comment: but how is the timer going to be initialized? Remember, the webhook function is a django view and it's only being called upon a web request. I don't get it - how and when is tm.start() being executed?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can use global variable.

Comment: @adshin21, I wouldn't recommend global variables for this. They're lost when the process restarts, they aren't shared across Gunicorn workers or similar, etc.